# Add New locale support in MONO .net framework

Tags: c#, .net, linux, mono, yocto

I am new to MONO, I want to add new locale(**Maori**) support in MONO.

**I am getting below exception:**

```
CultureNotSupportedExceptionSystem.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
        at System.Globalization.CultureTableRecord..ctor(String cultureName, Boolean useUserOverride)
        at System.Globalization.CultureTableRecord.GetCultureTableRecord(String name, Boolean useUserOverride)
        at System.Globalization.CultureInfo..ctor(String name, Boolean useUserOverride)
        at System.Globalization.CultureInfo..ctor(String name)
        at SmartDeviceProject2.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

**Here test code:**

```
namespace SmartDeviceProject2 {
    public class Program {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            CultureInfo cultureInfo = null;
            //string culname = "eu-ES"; //basque
            //string culname = "bg-BG"; //bulgarian - Culture found in CEOS
            string culname = "mi-NZ";   //maori
            //int culcode = 0x481;
            try {
                cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(culname);
            } catch (System.PlatformNotSupportedException e) {
                Console.WriteLine("PlatformNotSupportedException:{0}",e.ToString());
            } catch (System.ArgumentException e) {
                Console.WriteLine("CultureNotSupportedException{0}", e.ToString());
            }
            
            if (cultureInfo != null) {
                Console.WriteLine("Culture is found {0}", culname);
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine("Culture NOT found {0}", culname);
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me to added this Maori locale support in MONO?

Comment: why `yocto` tag?

Comment: Migrate to .NET 6 please. Mono is going away, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-end-of-mono/

Comment: I have used yocto to build my mono project that is what i have used yocto tage

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when moving a program from Windows to linux.  In our case it was the PNG culture that was missing.  Could not find any way to easily add it to the OS like in Windows, so just modified an existing culture in the program.
For us, all we wanted was just same as Australian culture, but with a different currency symbol (Kina rather than Dollars).

Not sure if this is any help, but here is the code we use.

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-AU");
            cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "K";
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
            Application.Init ();

            cultureInfo = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
            Console.WriteLine ("Main-:");
            Console.WriteLine ("{0,-33}{1,-25}", "DisplayName", cultureInfo.DisplayName);
            Console.WriteLine ("{0,-33}{1,-25}", "CurrencySymbol", cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol);
            
            MainWindow win = new MainWindow (args);
            win.Destroyed += new EventHandler(OnDestroyedEvent);
            win.Show ();
            Application.Run ();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Main exception: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried with your code, I am getting  " exception: Culture name mi-NZ is not supported".  I am using .NetFramwork 3.5.

Comment: Because the Maori NZ culture is not supported in Mono, a option would be to use an existing culture (e.g. the en-NZ culture) and change the properties that are different for mi-NZ.  You can change things  like DateTimeFormats, and Number formats.

Comment: any idea, How to add this locale support in MONO, Because requirement is to add  Maori support in platform level.